# 'readline' key bindings don't work properly in the default shell in Debian EC2 instance

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, debian, readline, terminal-emulator

I created a [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance. After I ssh into it, the default Bash shell is strange to me.
When I type in a command and want to edit the command before running it,

- moving the left arrow key doesn't move the cursor/pointer, and
- [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)-like key binding doesn’t work (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> doesn't jump the cursor/pointer to the leftmost place).

How can I make the shell more user friendly to me?

My terminal emulator is [Foot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Foot).

When I create a [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) instance, the readline problem for the Debian instance doesn't exist. So it depends on the image: Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: What's your terminal emulator, when connecting your ec2 instance? Putty or something? Any chance it would be misconfigured? Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419092/155682

Comment: @SYN it is foot. Does it need to be configured to be like Putty?

Comment: @SYN When I create a Ubuntu instance, the readline problem for the Debian instance doesn't exist. So it depends on the image: Ubuntu or Debian.